# Como rodar Node.JS no OpenShift e Localmente

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

Como rodar Node.JS no OpenShift (https://www.openshift.com/)?

URL do openshift: http://nodejs2-agenciadreamup.rhcloud.com/ 
GitHub: https://github.com/AlanPS/StreamBrasil/

Como rodar o NodeJS localmente, ele roda no IP localhost (127.0.0.1:porta) mas pelo IP da internet da vivo ele não conecta, como conectar?

Comment: Você viu esta página de documentação? https://www.openshift.com/developers/node-js

Comment: Tutorial: [Run Your Nodejs projects on OpenShift in Two Simple Steps](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps).

Comment: Já vi as páginas do openshift e fiz tudo que eles falam e não deu certo...segue alterações no post...

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 2):

Para configurar a sua aplicação para executar em portas diferentes no OpenShift e local, faça uso das variáveis de ambiente no OpenShift com a configuração, como em:

```
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT ||  process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT || 8080; 
var ipaddr = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP || 'localhost';

server.listen(port, ipaddr, function() {  
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```